# Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_8cx....... ]

Tags: build.gradle

[Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_8cx2vywotwpg6bx8qbm9rw0x0$_run_closure3@292cbb15] on root project 'Photoapp' of type org.gradle.api.Project.]